# How could I change this red background color coming from?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the red background.

EDIT: I mistakenly thought the red was css, but it was actually bitmap pixels in the jpeg image being loaded.

Refresh http://splambo.org/ until you get a header image that doesn't cover the entire width, and you'll see a red background color (in Chrome and Firefox, at least). Where is that red color coming from, and how do I change it?

Comment: It's the image itself that contains the red. The image URL must be redirecting to something with a red background. Sample redirect target with the red background: https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/defaultImage.small_1280_640_nofilter.jpg

Comment: Nailed it Jacob, thank you!

Comment: I'll try to answerify this somehow

Comment: Would it be considered best practice on StackOverflow to answer my own question after seeing your comment?

Comment: This works. Maybe some future stranger will have some similar mysterious background color and will see the tip of using the computed CSS technique. Personally, I think this having been closed is overkill, but SO is gonna SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For problems like this, it's best to use your browser's developer tools to inspect an element and look at computed CSS. This will tell you the effective styles that are applied and which stylesheet rules are responsible.

In this case, however, I saw while hovering on the `background-image` style that the image itself contained the red. If it was not the case, we'd see a `background-color` style and links to the responsible stylesheets.